# How to create a table (BigQuery) passing the schema and partition it to later insert data from a CSV in Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am currently creating a table by a schema, then I load data from a csv (full file) and I want to partition the table by ingestion date, but I don't know how.

```
    move_file_from_sftp_to_gcs_destination = SFTPToGCSOperator(
    task_id="Move_sftp_persona",
    source_path=os.path.join(TMP_PATH, OBJECT_SRC_1),
    sftp_conn_id='success_factor_sftp',
    destination_bucket=BUCKET_SRC,
    destination_path="maestro_dotacion/MaestroDotacionJobInfo-Componente1.csv",
)

csv_to_biguqery = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='csv_to_bigquery',
    bucket='bucket_name',
    source_objects=['file.csv'],
    field_delimiter =',',
    skip_leading_rows=3,
    destination_project_dataset_table='destination_name',
    source_format='CSV',
    schema_fields=
        [{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"users_sys_id","type":"STRING"},{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"num_personal","type":"STRING"},{'name': 'load_date', 'type': 'DATE', 'default': 'CURRENT_DATE'}],
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    time_partitioning={
        'field': 'load_date', 
        'type': 'DAY',  
        'require_partition_filter': True
    },
    dag=dag
```

I have read that it must be created by SQL, will it be so?

Comment: There's an easy way to do it manually, just create table in BQ , then upload your local csv and paste your json schema. you can also set the partition while creating